# CURDATE IN LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel-8

please i want to convert php code to use in laravel 8 blade file

SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE DATE(fecha) = CURDATE()

i used this but not working
@php
$horario = DB::table('horarios')->where('fecha', crudate())->get();
@endphp

Comment: try with time() if it's unix time or date('d-m-Y', time()) if a given format

Comment: I think a typo (in your example)  `...where('fecha', crudate())...` which probably should be `...where('fecha', curdate())...`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `whereDate()` found under https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

```php
$horarios = DB::table('horarios')
    ->whereDate('fecha', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->get();
```